# Symbolic Eigenvalues Matlab Error

Tags: matlab, rotation, symbolic-math, eigenvector

I'm trying to find the eigenvectors of a symbolic 3x3 rotation matrix in MATLAB, it appears to work for some inputs but not all, for example:

```
A =
[ cos(q), -sin(q), 0]
[ sin(q), cos(q), 0]
[ 0, 0, 1]

[V,lambda]=eig(A)

V =
[ 0, -i, i]
[ 0, 1, 1]
[ 1, 0, 0]

lambda =
[ 1, 0, 0]
[ 0, cos(q) - sin(q)*i, 0]
[ 0, 0, cos(q) + sin(q)*i]
```

this works fine, however if I try something which is not a rotation about a unit axis (x,y,z) I get the following error:

```
A =
[ cos(q), -sin(q), 0]
[ 0, 0, -1]
[ sin(q), cos(q), 0]

>> [V,lambda]=eig(A)
Warning: basis of eigenspace for eigenvalue cos(q)/3 - (cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 +
(cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 + (cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)/(2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 +
((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/... [linalg::eigenvectors] 
??? Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Unable to find explicit eigenvectors.

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.mupadmexnout at 2003
out = mupadmex(fcn,args{:});

Error in ==> sym.eig at 68
[V,D,p] = mupadmexnout('mllib::eigenvectors',A);
```

I'm using the eigenvalues to find the axis of rotation of the matrix, and I need to use it for much more complicated systems

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the error (tested on MATLAB R2010b):

```
syms q
A = [cos(q) -sin(q) 0 ; 0 0 -1 ; sin(q) cos(q) 0]
[V,lambda] = eig(A)
```

I get the following (rather long) result:

```
A =
[ cos(q), -sin(q),  0]
[      0,       0, -1]
[ sin(q),  cos(q),  0]

V =
[ (3*cos(q)^2 + 4*cos(q)^3 + cos(q)^4 + 27*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(4/3) + 9*cos(q)*sin(q)^2 + 9*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) - 6*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 9*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 2*cos(q)^3*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 18*cos(q)*(cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))/(3*sin(q)*(cos(q)^2 - 3*cos(q) + 9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 3*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3))*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)), (3*cos(q)^2 - 27*3^(1/2)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(4/3)*i + 4*cos(q)^3 + cos(q)^4 + 27*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(4/3) + 9*cos(q)*sin(q)^2 - 18*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) - 6*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) - 18*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 2*cos(q)^3*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 3*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*i + 4*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^3*i + 3^(1/2)*cos(q)^4*i + 18*cos(q)*(cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2) + 6*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)*i - 2*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^3*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)*i + 18*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*(cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2)*i + 9*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*sin(q)^2*i)/(3*sin(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)*(cos(q)^2 + 9*3^(1/2)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3)*i - 3*cos(q) + 9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) - 6*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 3*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*i - 3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*i)), -(27*3^(1/2)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(4/3)*i + 3*cos(q)^2 + 4*cos(q)^3 + cos(q)^4 + 27*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(4/3) + 9*cos(q)*sin(q)^2 - 18*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) - 6*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) - 18*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 2*cos(q)^3*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) - 3*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*i - 4*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^3*i - 3^(1/2)*cos(q)^4*i + 18*cos(q)*(cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2) - 6*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)*i + 2*3^(1/2)*cos(q)^3*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)*i - 18*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*(cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2)*i - 9*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*sin(q)^2*i)/(3*sin(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)*(3*cos(q) + 9*3^(1/2)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3)*i - cos(q)^2 - 9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 6*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 3*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*i - 3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*i))]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -(9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3))/(cos(q)^2 - 3*cos(q) + 9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 3*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             (18*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3))/(cos(q)^2 + 9*3^(1/2)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3)*i - 3*cos(q) + 9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) - 6*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 3*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*i - 3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*i),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -(18*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3))/(3*cos(q) + 9*3^(1/2)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3)*i - cos(q)^2 - 9*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(2/3) + 6*cos(q)*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + (cos(q)^5/27 + (2*cos(q)^4)/27 + (cos(q)^3*sin(q)^2)/27 + cos(q)^3/27 + (cos(q)^2*sin(q)^2)/3 + sin(q)^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + 3*3^(1/2)*cos(q)*i - 3^(1/2)*cos(q)^2*i)]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1]

lambda =
[ cos(q)/3 + (cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3) - (cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)/(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, cos(q)/3 - (cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 + (cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)/(2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3)) - (3^(1/2)*((cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3) + (cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)/(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3))*i)/2,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0, cos(q)/3 - (cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 + (cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)/(2*(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3)) + (3^(1/2)*((cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3) + (cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)/(cos(q)^2/3 + cos(q)^3/27 + sin(q)^2/2 + ((cos(q)/3 - cos(q)^2/9)^3 + (cos(q)^3/27 + cos(q)^2/3 + sin(q)^2/2)^2)^(1/2))^(1/3))*i)/2]
```

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code directly into (Matlab R2010a) and I get the same error as before, very strange,

Comment: @Max: It's probably a bug in that version. I tested it with both R2010a and R2010b. I get the error in a, but it works fine in b. For now, if you do not have access to the newer version(s), just post your particular matrix here and I'll post the solution for you.

Comment: @yoda: Thanks but the matrices are very long expressions and very numerous, the work around (angle axis theorem) is doing what I need at the moment, but I think I'll look to migrate to Maple for symbolic work in the long term

Answer (score 0):

The problematic example you gave is not a general rotation matrix, 1 is not an eigenvalue.   See more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.  This shouldn't affect the matlab function however, you are guaranteed a basis of generalized eigenvectors over the complex numbers.   Do you have any more information about the error?   I'm noticing some calls to symmetric matrix-based functions, have you tried calling eig with the option 'qz' to explicitly call the non-symmetric based algorithm?

Comment: The matrices I am working with are symmetric so I believe 'qz' will not work, the rotation matrix is not a pure rotation around x,y,z rather a combination of them. The only information I have on the error I'm afraid is that which is printed on screen, right now i am using an angle-axis theorom which is working fine.

Comment: Tried it on my version like yoda and it worked so it is likely a bug specific to your version.  Also your matrix example is actually a composition of two reflections and a rotation:  [1,0,0;0,0,1;0,1,0]*[1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,-1]*[cos(q),-sin(q),0;sin(q),cos(q),0;0,0,0].

Comment: Also, performing eig(A,eye(3),'qz') where A is your example also worked.  The 'qz' flag does not require symmetry in A, it means don't try to use symmetry in the algorithm.